# Passing innerHtml value as parameter for play framework routes

Tags: html, playframework, routes

hello i am trying to pass inline edited table value as a parameter to play routes can someone help me with the same 
here is my html code

```
<table class="gradienttable">
        <thead>
                <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
             <th>TimeSheetdate</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>IsBilled</th>
             <th>Work Place</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
               @for(element <- CurrentPage) {
                        <tr>
                             <td contenteditable="true" id="task1">@element.getTask()</td>
                 <td>@element.getTimeSheetDate()</td>
                 <td contenteditable="true" id="hours">@element.getHours()</td>
                 <td contenteditable="true" id="isbilled">@element.getIsBilled()</td>
                 <td contenteditable="true"id="workplace">@element.getWorkPlace()</td>
                <td><a href="@{routes.Application.edit(task1.innerHTML)}" ><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/edit.jpg")" alt="EDIT" style="width:20px;height:20px"></a>
                            </tr>
                    } 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

routes

```
GET     /Application/edit            controllers.Application.edit(task1:String)
```

application.java

```
public static Result edit(String task1)
    {
        return ok(DisplayTimeSheet.render(task1));
    }
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the server-side rendered Scala template with the DOM actions of the client.  For `@{routes.Application.edit(task1.innerHTML)}`, `task1` doesn't exist as far as the non-DOM template is concerned.

Your use of `<a href="...">` is kind of weird, because that would make a synchronous call and if you're into inline editing then maybe that's not what you want.  This answer covers an asynchronous approach using Play's JavaScript router support (which, if  you haven't seen it before, is very cool).

You'll need to expose `edit` in the JavaScript router:

```
// You can also return an F.Promise<Result>
public static Result jsRoutes() {
response().setContentType("text/javascript");
return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("appRoutes", //appRoutes will be the JS object available in our view
                                  routes.javascript.Application.edit()));
```

}

And then expose that method in the routes:

```
GET           /assets/js/routes             controllers.Application.jsRoutes()
```

That will generate a chunk of JavaScript that you can import

```
<script src="@controllers.routes.Application.jsRoutes()" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And finally, write some JavaScript to handle the inline editing completion.

```
function doInlineEdit(taskName) {
    appRoutes.controllers.Application.edit(taskName).ajax( {
      success : function ( data ) {
        target.closest('li').remove();
      }
    });
}
```

Then you just need to wire that method to be called when your inline-editable element changes content.

You can find additional info [here](http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=734).